# Matched Range Merge in R

Tags: arrays, r, merge, range, match

I would like to merge/combine two files, so that if an entry in column B of my first file falls into the range of columns B and C in my second file, the output will contain all of the information contained in both files.

Like this:

file 1

```
     A      B
    rs10    23353
    rs100   10000
    rs234   54440
```

file 2

```
    A        B      C
    E235    20000   30000
    E255    50000   60000
```

where, because 23353 falls between 20000 and 30000, and 54440 falls between 50000 and 60000 the output file would look like this:

```
rs      23353   E235    20000   30000
rs234   54440   E255    50000   60000
```

and rs100 would be removed (from the output file) because it does not fall within a range of any row in file 2.

any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: This question was more complicated than indicated here. The solution can be found here: [Merge by Range in R - Applying Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892241/merge-by-range-in-r-applying-loops), and is delivered by using the `GenomicRanges`package in Bioconductor. Very useful package!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick.  You could probably make it more concise, but to elucidate all the steps I made it overly obvious.

```
NewMatrixCol1 <- c()
NewMatrixCol2 <- c()
NewMatrixCol3 <- c()
NewMatrixCol4 <- c()
NewMatrixCol5 <- c()

for (i in 1:length(file1$A)) {
    for (j in 1:length(file2$A)) {
        LowNumber <- file2$B[j]
        HighNumber <- file2$C[j]
        if (LowNumber <= file1$B[i] & file1$B[i]  <= HighNumber) {
            append(NewMatrixCol1, file1$A[i])
            append(NewMatrixCol2, file1$B[i])
            append(NewMatrixCol3, file2$A[j])
            append(NewMatrixCol4, file2$B[j])
            append(NewMatrixCol5, file2$C[j])
        } else {}
    }
}

dataframe <- data.frame(Col1 = NewMatrixCol1, Col2 = NewMatrixCol2, Col3 = NewMatrixCol3, Col4 = NewMatrixCol4, Col5 = NewMatrixCol5)
```

EDIT1:  I misunderstood the question, and am now working on it.

EDIT2:  This new solution should work as indicated.

EDIT3:  There was a missing `)`, as indicated by mfk534.

Comment: I appreciate the overly obvious aspect ... conciseness can come later. Thanks, Mike!

Comment: Just also, FYI for anyone else who comes across this and might repurpose - the first line in Mike's code needs a closing ) .. as in, for (i in length(file1$A)) {

Comment: I've added the closing `)` that was missing.  You are quite welcome, hope this works well for you!

Comment: @MikeZ, can you double check the answer you've posted here? As it is, it's not working for me. One mistake I see is in `Col4` and `Col5` in the last line.

Comment: It ran with my data but produced an empty file - I fiddled with a few things and am now getting an error: Error in if (LowNumber <= file1$B[i] & file1$B[i] <= HighNumber) { : 
  argument is of length zero

Comment: Try converting the initial matrix to a data frame by using `as.data.frame()`.  There might be an indexing error in this case, as the convention I was using was for a data frame.

Comment: error message stays the same: `Error in if (LowNumber <= file1$B[i] & file1$B[i] <= HighNumber) { : 
  argument is of length zero `

Comment: Okay, I added `1:` to the `for` loops.  This should solve the problem.  Initially it was `in length(...)`, now it is `in 1:length(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I see you've already accepted an answer, but here is another possible solution.

This function was just hacked together, but could be worked on some more to be made more generalized.

```
myfun = function(DATA1, DATA2, MATCH1, MIN, MAX) {
  temp = sapply(1:nrow(DATA2), 
                function(x) DATA1[[MATCH1]] >= DATA2[[MIN]][x] &
                  DATA1[[MATCH1]] <= DATA2[[MAX]][x])
  if (isTRUE(any(rowSums(temp) == 0))) {
    temp1 = DATA1[-(which(rowSums(temp) == 0)), ]
  }
  OUT = cbind(temp1[order(temp1[[MATCH1]]), ], 
              DATA2[order(DATA2[[MIN]]), ], row.names=NULL)
  condition = ((OUT[4] <= OUT[2] & OUT[2] <= OUT[5]) == 0)
  if (isTRUE(any(condition))) {
    OUT[-which(condition), ]
  } else {
    OUT
  }
}
```

Here's what the function does:

1. It first compares, row by row, the value in the second column of the first `data.frame` with the values in the second and third columns of the second `data.frame`.
2. It then checks to find if any of those has `FALSE` for both conditions, and removes them from the first `data.frame`.
3. Then, it sorts the first `data.frame` by the second column, and the second `data.frame` by the "min" match column.
4. Finally, it does one more check to ensure that the value from the first dataset is between the provided values; if not, that row is removed.

Now, here is some sample data. `A` and `B` are the same as your provided data. `X` and `Y` have been changed for further testing purposes. In the merge between `X` and `Y`, there should be only one row.

```
A = read.table(header=TRUE, text="A      B
    rs10    23353
    rs100   10000
    rs234   54440")

B = read.table(header=TRUE, text="A        B      C
    E235    20000   30000
    E255    50000   60000")

X = A[c(3, 1, 2), ]
X[1, 2] = 57000
Y = B
Y[2, 3] = 55000
```

Here's how you would use the function and the output you would get.

```
myfun(A, B, 2, 2, 3)
#       A     B    A     B     C
# 1  rs10 23353 E235 20000 30000
# 2 rs234 54440 E255 50000 60000
myfun(X, Y, 2, 2, 3)
#      A     B    A     B     C
# 1 rs10 23353 E235 20000 30000
```

Comment: Hi - so with your solution I'm having an issue because the two files I'm using are of different lengths: `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 438, 21976` Do you have any suggestions?